Can't add a dot after a i18n variable
I am trying to use i18n with Vue3 and the variable feature in it. I have a translation like this:
 "documents-button": "Please see @:navigation.documents"

And then under navigation I have this variable "documents": "Documents" and all works fine when I put it out in my component sort of like this:
<div>{{ $t('documents-button') }}</div>

The problem is that I want to put a dot at the end of the resulting button text so it says "Please see Documents.".
I tried this:
"documents-button": "Please see @:navigation.documents."

But now it seems to look for a variable "navigation.documents." which of course doesn't exist. If I instead try:
"documents-button": "Please see @:navigation.documents ."

Then it puts a space and result is instead "Please see Documents .".
How can I get a dot in the end without a space, so the result is "Please see Documents."?
Ps.

I can't put the dot in navigation.documents variable since it is used in other places and some of which it should not have a dot behind it.
I can't put the dot in the html since I loop through many objects and some translations already have a dot so they would get double dots, if that makes sense.

I therefore need it in the documents-button variable translation.

You could replace the dot with its HTML char equivalent:  "documents-button": "Please see @:navigation.documents&#8901;" Or you could create a dot: '.' variable and use @:navigation.documents@:dot. Right?

This might also work: @:navigation.documents\.

Addding a dot (period) variable worked. None of the other worked. However, the solution seems to be a bit "hacky". Aren't you supposed to be able to have things after the variable name? It could also be like -, /, ( or anything else.

I fail to understand why placing a dot in a variable and using that variable is hacky. A dot in a variable name is interpreted as "dot operator" and allows nesting. We want that to work as intended, right? So, when you place a dot there with another meaning (e.g: it's just text content), you have to either escape it (and apparently none of the common methods work) or to provide it in another way (e.g: via a variable). Why is it hacky? By the way: ; might end the variable name and not get displayed (try @:navigation.documents;.).

@tao It is hacky since I would have to do this with all kind of special characters which are usually placed next to words, as the examples I put in my previous response. I would assume it is sort of a normal thing to want a period after a sentence next to a variable, could be email address like "Please contact us on @:email."
